# Unable to install AudioKit 4.11 via CocoaPods in Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, audiokit

I am having difficulty installing AudioKit 4.11 in an iOS app via CocoaPods using Xcode 12. I am using CocoaPods version 1.10.0.rc.1.

I took the following steps:

1. Created new iOS project using  Life Cycle option 'UIKit App Delegate'. I set target deployment to iOS 13.6. I called my project '411'.
2. I installed AudioKit 4.11 using the following Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '13.6'

target '411' do

    use_frameworks!

    pod 'AudioKit'

end
```

After installing the pod, I could build the app and install it on my phone. However, I saw an Xcode warning suggesting I set a minimum deploment target for AudioKit of 12.0. I clicked Perform Changes to accept this suggestion and built again. The warning went away.

3. I added the line "import AudioKit" to ContentView.swift, immediately under the 'import SwiftUI' statement. As soon as I did this, Xcode displayed the message "*Failed to build module 'AudioKit' from its module interface; it may have been damaged or it may have triggered a bug in the Swift compiler when it was produced*"

Comment: This is issue being covered right now at https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/2267